# Can't find an infinite loop but it's running with one?

Tags: java, loops, infinite

I'm using only a piece of my entire program, but I'm 100% certain it lies in this method.

```
public void draw() 
{
    int count;
    int arrowHeadRight = getIndentationLevel() 
            + getBaseLength() / 2;
    for (count = 0; count < arrowHeadRight; count++)
    {
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    System.out.println(drawingCharacter);
    int baseAtCenter = getBaseLength() / 2 - 1;
    int arrowHeadLeft = 1;
    for (count = 1; count <= baseAtCenter; count++)
    {
        for (count = 0; count < arrowHeadRight--; count++)
        {
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        System.out.print(drawingCharacter);
        for (count = 0; count < arrowHeadLeft; count++)
        {
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        System.out.print(drawingCharacter);
        arrowHeadLeft = arrowHeadLeft + 2;
    }
    for (count = 0; count < arrowHeadRight--; count++)
    {
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    for (count = 1; count <= getBaseLength(); count++)
    {
        System.out.print(drawingCharacter);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    //Arrow Shaft
    for (count = 1; count <= shaftLength; count++)
    {
        for (count = 0; count < arrowHeadRight; count++)
        {
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        System.out.println(drawingCharacter);
    }
}
```

Now assuming that all the variables in the `for` loops are all greater than the `count` variable, where would there be an infinite loop? I've checked it over so many times that my eyes hurt, and having a fresh pair look at this would be helpful.

Comment: You're nesting for loops, loops that use the **same count index variable**. That's extremely dangerous -- Why are you doing this?

Comment: Matt can you not single step through in a debugger and find out what's happening?

Comment: This means that you're changing the loop index variable inside of the loop, again a dangerous thing to do. Much better to give each for loop its own index variable.

Comment: GetBaseLength() is also reevaluated on every iteration of one of your loops - how is the return value determined?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Because I'm a tired uni student with a CompSci assignment due in 2 hours and want to go to bed.

Comment: The return value for GetBaseLength is simply return baseLength, which is determined in the setter

Comment: Ironically, if you change the definition of your variables and reinitialized them every time through (so `for(int count = 0...)`, you'd see the main issue right away as the compiler would light up like a Christmas tree.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger please...  and with bunch of `System.out.println`s, shouldn't it be easy to identify which part is completed and which part is still running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the part of code with the problem:

```
for (count = 1; count <= shaftLength; count++)
{
    for (count = 0; count < arrowHeadRight; count++)
    {
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    System.out.println("drawingCharacter");
}
```

You are starting a for loop with index `count=1` then starting another loop inside of it resting the index `count` to 0. After the inner loop, count will now be equal to `arrowHeadRight`, not what it was when you entered the loop.

Your entire method is full of similar examples.

Solution would be to use different index variables when using nested for loops like this:

```
for (count = 1; count <= shaftLength; count++)
    {
        for (int count2 = 0; count2 < arrowHeadRight; count2++)
        {
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        System.out.println(drawingCharacter);
    }
```

Comment: Did this, didn't work. Took me until you put up the solution for me to realize I didn't change `count++`

I am very tired. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your infinite loop:

```
for (count = 1; count <= shaftLength; count++)
    {
        for (count = 0; count < arrowHeadRight; count++)
        {
```

Each time the inner loop terminates, `count` will equal `arrowHeadRight`. If `arrowHeadRight <= shaftLength` then the outer loop will never terminate.